# Grab bitpay invoice id from php

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have tried to grab bitpay invoice id from callback but couldn't go through can you guys help me with how to correctly grab bitpay invoice id to insert to mysql database with php

Comment: what have u tried so far ? Code ?

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);  and then php code actually i am new to this bitpay invoice id callback thing if you can give me easy to understand and nice answer it would be very helpful

Comment: i think u missunderstand https://bitpay.com/docs/invoice-callbacks . its an IPN wich means the bitpay Server sends u a POST not file_get_contents from a page. u have to Setup in bitpay the IPN callback URL, then u define ur script `print_r($_POST)` and then u get ur VARS

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following to obtain the invoice ID from the POSTED callback:

`$invoiceId = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;`

As per the data returned from the invoice API as per their [documentation](https://bitpay.com/docs/invoice-callbacks)

Comment: thanks for quick reply ryan but can please explain more from that invoice we pay in https://test.bitpay.com/invoice?id=MuF2NVPJRUhXu4iQEnC5Jv something like here

Comment: If your using their IPN solution, this value above is present in the callback they return to your callback url.